# Salesforce REST Api Chatter user Request "The requested resource does not exist"

Tags: chatter, user

I am trying to get a list of users through the [chatter user API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_retrieve_info_for_list_of_users.htm) (**services/data/v54.0/chatter/users**). I am getting the correct result on one salesforce account. But on the other salesforce account, I am getting this error:

```
 {
    "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
  }
```

That is the only API I found in the documentation of salesforce to get a list of all users. Can anybody tell me ? what am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Can you try with 52 or 53(services/data/v52.0/chatter/users)? Does user has API enabled perm on profile ?

Comment: @Vinay yes, I can see API Enabled permission is selected in the user's profile. Also, I tried changing to v53.0 and v52.0. Don't think it is a Salesforce API's version issue. Thanks for your suggestion btw.